# Escape user input in windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a windows batch file that accepts a password as user input:

```
SET /P PASSWORD=Password:
```

This password might have characters that need escaping like `!`. The `PASSWORD` variable then gets passed to other batch files using `CALL`

```
CALL Foo.Bat %PASSWORD%
```

How can I ensure that special characters get escaped and passed correctly as parameter? For example if the user inputs `!%"£$"` I want `%1` to be `!%"£$"` in `Foo.bat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a nice challenge, but this is advanced batch technic.
I would use here a simpler way, use delayed expansion and do not send the content, only the variable name.

This is absolute safe even with special characters.

```
call foo.bat password
```

Foo.bat -----------------

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Echo !password!
```

**EDIT: Solution for the original question,

this is a way to solve it with the content instead of an variable name**

It's necessary to prepare the content before *sending* it via CALL to second batch file.
It's hard to use something like `CALL foo.bat %preparedVariable%`
It's seems to be better to use `CALL foo.bat !preparedVariable!`
But even then I fail at the doubling of carets by the CALL-phase.

But then I found a simple way to use the percent expansion just after the CALL-phase.

```
@echo off

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
rem set /p "complex=Complex Input "
set "complex=xx! & "!^&"ab^^ " ^^^^cd%%"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :prepareForCallBatch complex PreparedParam
echo Send   =!PreparedParam!#
set complex
echo(
call ShowParam.bat %%PreparedParam%%
exit /b

:: Prepare special characters &|<>"^ for a batch call
:prepareForCallBatch
set "temp=!%~1!"

set "temp=!temp:^=^^!"
set "temp=!temp:&=^&!"
set "temp=!temp:|=^|!"
set "temp=!temp:<=^<!"
set "temp=!temp:>=^>!"
set "temp=!temp:"=^^"!"
set "%~2=!temp!"
exit /b
```

To see the *real* parameters in ShowParam.bat I use something like this
*ShowParam.bat*

```
@echo off
setlocal
set prompt=
@echo on
REM # %* #
```

Comment: Or `Echo !%~1!` since the name of the variable was passed as a parameter.

Comment: @dbenham- yes that was my intention, but I forgot it while writing :-)

Comment: @dbenham, Aacini, Joey, PA. and the other _pro's_: Is it possible to solve it as the OP first asks?

Comment: @jeb - That is a nasty problem (as you know). Difficult to solve perfectly if you allow the target batch to be called both directly and via CALL (or even multiple CALLs) - you must know the number of escapes to apply. Then there is doubling of quoted carets, and then possibility of delayed expansion enabled or disabled, with or without `!` in content. Not worth the effort in my mind. I once had a script of callable batch functions that tried to use literal string arguments - it was a nightmare. I abandoned the effort long ago.

Comment: @jeb: The only way is to prepare the variable value by inserting carets, doubling percents, etc. prior to be passed to the subroutine. This have too many special cases and the result obtained is of little value. As Dave said: it just not worth the effort...

Comment: @Aacini, dbenham: I first tried also to doubling and escaping all, but failed and cannot founnd any solution for the caret doubling, but then I saw the simple solution of using not the delayed expansion, instead I used late percent expansion now

Comment: @jeb - nice work. I'm kind of glad my knowledge of Windows batch files is so limited.